# GQL Mutation: why the logout mutation, when destroyng the session, is returning and exposing whatever is inside the context

Tags: node.js, express, graphql

I'm having a critical issue with a mutation in my NodeJS and GraphQL API.

PKGs versions:

- "node": "~16"
- "express-session": "^1.17.3",
- "graphql": "^16.6.0",
- Do you need more please comment asking what packages you want to see the versions

When a user is logging out the session is destroyed and that works but as the result, we are exposing everything that is in the context.

I want only to result as true/false as per type is Boolean

the details

```js
extend type Mutation {
  # Destroy the session of the user
  logout: Boolean
}
```

Resolver

```js
export default {
  Mutation: {
    logout: {
      resolve(parent, args, context) {
        console.log('context: ', context);
        return context.session.destroy(error => {
          if (error) {
            log.info('Logging out: could not destroy the session');
            log.error(error);
            return false;
          }
          console.log('HELLO LOGOUT');
          log.info('Logged out: session destroyed.');
          return true;
        });
      },
    },
  },
};
```

This above resulting as follow

```bash
 "GraphQLError: Boolean cannot represent a non boolean value: { cookie: [Object], passport: { user: [Object] }, etc ...
```

From this method, I want to destroy the session and return the Boolean only.

How can I modify this method to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning `return context.session.destroy` which is a promise instead of a boolean. Nothing after that matters since that function is async. You need to `await` the result before returning.

```
export default {
  Mutation: {
    logout: async (parent, args, context) => {
      try {
        await context.session.destroy();
        return true;
      catch(error) {
        log.info('Logging out: could not destroy the session');
        log.error(error);
        return false;
      },
    },
  },
};
```